# JSF 2 Access on Facelet Files

Tags: jsf-2, facelets

I am starting to explore JSF 2 facelet and I would like to test this in a simple project.

I just have some query regarding the file structure in JSF 2.  When I was using Spring,
I use to put all my pages under WEB-INF so that they wont be accessible to the browser.

I notice in JSF 2, you should put your *.xhtml outside of WEB-INF and allow access to them thru
the Faces Servlet.

Question, does this mean that all enterprise application that utilizes JSF always put
a security constraint in their web.xml?

```
<security-constraint>
    <web-resource-collection>
        <web-resource-name>XHTML files</web-resource-name>
        <url-pattern>*.xhtml</url-pattern>
    </web-resource-collection>
    <auth-constraint />
</security-constraint>
```

Or they are using some sort of a filter, that traps all incoming request and then reject request
that has *.xhtml?

Is my understanding correct and if so which one is more apt to be used?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A third alternative in JSF 2.x is to map the `FacesServlet` just straight on `*.xhtml` instead of `*.jsf` or whatever. This way you don't need to cobble with security constraints or filters to prevent endusers from directly accessing `*.xhtml` files. It has the only disadvantage that you cannot serve "plain vanilla" XHTML files without invoking the `FacesServlet`, but that would in turn already not make much sense, because such files should technically have the `*.html` extension.

Please note that this doesn't work in old JSF 1.x. The `FacesServlet` would run in an infinite loop invoking itself again and again.

Comment: so does this confirm my understanding regarding the two approach that I have stated above? Thanks also for this third approach cause I have never thought or read about this?

Comment: Yes your understanding was correct. That was the way how they did for JSF 1.x. It will also work for JSF 2.x, but that's thus not necessary if you just map the `FacesServlet` on the same view extension.

Comment: Thanks for always being helpful! (I actually forgot how many times, I said thanks to you...) =)